# Delay Mains power after a blackout

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My parents live in a country with very unreliable electricity. Something that happens very frequently is mains power will go out and when it comes back it will flicker for a couple of minutes. It has destroyed some of my parent's appliances already.

I'm looking for a device I could use to setup a delay timer (hopefully on the breaker box, but if not protecting each appliance) so that power to the house is delayed until there is continuous power for 2 minutes or so.

Is there anything like this? Would it possible to build such a thing if there is not?

Comment: Is it destroying all the appliances, or just specific ones? If the latter, which appliances are they?  Does your parents' homeland use 230VAC IEC-style power or 120/240VAC North American-style power?

Comment: They use 120V. They've already lost a refrigerator and a computer. There is likely a surge component to the.problem, but there is also the flickering issue which is more destructive

Comment: You'd have to do it live or pull the meter. That's not very DiY. A [random 90amp contacter](https://www.grainger.com/product/2CG01?g) that I looked up is about $400... And you'd need an enclosure just for that, a microcontroller (TDR), and I'm guessing: a car battery to power that and a charging system for the battery. Shopping is off-topic, but if anyone makes this for less than a $1000 I'm all ears, +1

Comment: @CarlosG. -- how many appliances are we concerned about here?

Answer (score 1):

An application for a **time delay relay** though in most cases you'd need that driving the control/coil of a heavy duty relay/"contactor" to actually switch appliance or whole-house power, as most time delay relays (**TDR**s) are fairly low current devices. One to switch whole house power will probably be expensive, but one for each circuit will add up, so you'll have to make that call based on what you find when shopping.

TDRs are a standard industrial item, widely available in many configurations. While you may not be aware of them, many consumer devices have one built in (i.e. my air conditioner has to have had power for 3 or 5 minutes (I don't recall which) before it will start the compressor, so that a an outage or being unplugged does not result in trying to start the compressor before it's ready to be started without damaging itself, if it had been running before the power went out.

Comment: The air conditioner delay may be part of a strategy to prevent **short cycles**.  E.G. if the unit is unable to store "state" or measure the passage of time.